# Haskell: gtksourceview2 library duplicate code

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need the the following library for my development: gtksourceview2.

However, gtksourceview2 is broken:

- [gtksourceview2-0.12.3.1 broken with cabal because of duplicate code](http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1289)

what can I do to install it anyway? I can change the haskell files if I know how I can do that when running cabal install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distribution.Simple.Utils.moreRecentFile` function comes from `Cabal`, it was added in `1.18.*` series. `gtksourceview2` uses custom build script, and it is very sensitive to changes in `Cabal` library. Try to install it using older `Cabal` version. E.g. `cabal install gtksourceview2 --cabal-lib-version=1.16.0`